# Eclipse console does not print standard error

Tags: c, linux, eclipse-cdt

What happens is that the .c files are not printing well to Eclipse's console.

`printfs()` print to console like they should but errors are not being showed.

I've tried:
-Go to Window->Preferences->Run/Debug->Console the option "Show when program writes to standard error" is toggled on.

My OP is Linux Cinnamon 32-bit.

Note: If I use the terminal it shows the errors of the program in question.